# How to answer hiring managers' e-mails when I don't fit the job titles?

Tags: hiring-process, email, employees

After I had signed up for websites, such as monster.com, linkedin.com, and indeed.com, hiring managers started sending me a lot of e-mails. I see that I don't fit the job titles or don't have enough experience. E.g., they require 5 or 6 years in software development, but I have 3, including one-year internship. Or they send me a Project Manager job description whereas I am a software developer.

I don't want to ignore them because there might be an opportunity. What answers would be good? Even if they send me wrong job descriptions, they might have an opening I am interested in.

Comment: I am very confused by your question.  You seem to understand that you do not have to respond but that you are surrendering an opportunity to network but not responding.  What are you wanting to know

Comment: If the role is 'software developer' and matches what you generally do, it can't hurt to respond, even if the skills are mismatched.  If the roles are clearly outside your interests, don't bother.  Even if these interviews prove to be an embarrassment, you'll learn stuff from them. Do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it depends on your free time and level of desperation.  I typically do not.

When you've got your resume out in an open forum, anyone and everyone can see it and contact you about it.  You really have no idea whether the person contacting you is knowledgeable about your field, aware of the difference between what you want and what they are offering, or even marginally capable of getting you a good job.  It's about one step more efficient than talking to random people on the street about job opportunities.

It's possible that the people you make contact with will be clever and efficient recruiters.  It's possible they will be the human equivalent of search engines.  The big thing to remember here is that they aren't here to find an opportunity for you, they are here to make money for themselves.  *Some* recruiters do that buy competently building a network of employers and employees that allows them to find great matches.  Others do that by simply trying to find as many contacts as possible.  I've experienced all ends of the spectrum from the "cold call".

The mark of distinction I've found is that a truly able recruiter will contact you with meaningful opportunities and qualify their message with some sort of statement that suggests they read and understand something about your.  For example:

> Hello bethlakshmi, 
>   I noticed from your LinkedIn that you have a background in big companies but a love doing pioneering work in small teams.  I have a job that would fit your skills well, although it's a smaller company than you are used to.  Please take a look and see if it fits.

Chances are with a message like that, the recruiter is actually willing to spend enough time grooming our relationship to keep his eyes open for me in the future and throw me other opportunities, even this one is a miss.

But the generic "let me tell you all about this job that isn't at all what you do for a living" often even ends with "and if you don't fit, I'd love it if you could pass this along to anyone you might feel is appropriate".  This essentially tells me:

- The recruiter either doesn't know or couldn't bother to check even the moderately important details about my profile
- The recruiter really doesn't care if I fit the bill, as long as they can claim they made a contact.
- The recruiter wants me to do his work for him and enlarge his network.

If he was interested in a relationship, he'd have taken the time to both understand the poorness of the fit, and explain why it was worth my while to even read the email.  I consider it spam at this point, and refuse to even justify it with a response.

CAVEAT - the one caveat I have is that years of experience are rarely an absolute.  If you are hearing years that are a few years off of your own experience level, but the job is otherwise interesting to you, it may be worth a reachout.  Years of experience are never really a perfect way of describing experience, and I'd encourage anyone to go for it and let the company be the judge of your skills.

Comment: I've seen job postings where they ask for years of experience in technologies/libraries that have only been public for a year or so. The "years of experience" requirements are generally just ballpark numbers.